# Python Numpy can't convert Strings to Integers from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I read a CSV File and everythings works except the conversion of the values to integers, since all the values there are strings. I tried to convert column-wise in a loop like this:

```
counter = 0
while counter < len(data):
    try:
        data[counter,0] = data[counter,0].astype(int) # ID
        data[counter,1] = data[counter,1].astype(int) # Survived
    except ValueError:
        pass
    counter = counter + 1
```

As you can see it is the titanic dataset I try to work with.

`print (type(data[0,0]))`

And printing the type of a value gives me `<class 'numpy.str_'>`

How do I properly convert the columns to integers? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to change 1 item at a time without changing the dtype of `data`. Note that `data.dtype` tells you the type of the `ndarray` and you can't change that one cell at a time - the entire `ndarray` has a single type. Try this instead: `data = data.astype(int)`. That will convert all rows and all columns to integers at once.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found out that `pandas` is converting all the datatypes automatically with following code:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("filename.csv")
```